# stty: invalid integer argument: «CCPP»

Tags: zsh

I tried this in a terminal session where I am using the Z shell:

```
stty erase ^M
```

and I got this message:

```
stty: invalid integer argument: «CCPP»
```

I don't know what to do.

Comment: Not erroneously tagging your question with the wrong shell would be a start.  The question itself gives away that you are _not_ using the Bourne Again shell.

Comment: @JdeBP I'd be interested in knowing what shell he _is_ using, and possibly why he'd like to make enter act like erase...

Comment: There you go.  And now the answer.  Only the questioner can explain why xe wants to do this in the first place, though.  (-:

Comment: i'm using Zsh, sorry for my bad english

Comment: i'm reading THE UNIX PROGRAMMING ENVIRONMENT of Kernighan$Pike and i just tried and example from that book

Answer (score 2):

In the Z shell, the `^` character is an *extended globbing* character that is recognized by the *filename expansion* part of command processing.

As the Z shell manual explains, the pattern `^M` matches any filename *except* one that matches the pattern `M`.  So what is happening is that the command is being expanded to `stty erase` followed by all of the filenames in the current directory *except one named `M`* if there is one.

It is simply the case that you have a file named `«CCPP»` in the current directory that is the first in the resultant list when the `^M` globbing pattern is expanded.

Quote or escape the metacharacter:

- `stty erase '^M'`
- `stty erase \^M`

Or turn off the Z shell's extended globbing:

- `setopt no_extended_glob`

Compare the experience of [this person](https://linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/backspace-key-mapping-in-vi-199544-print/) who had a different filename and whose exclusion pattern was `?`.  The person at https://askubuntu.com/a/206722/43344 actually did the aforementioned quoting, and genuinely supplied an argument (a string comprising 3 characters rather than a specifier of exactly 1 character) that was invalid.

Of course, CR is a bizarre choice for an `erase` special character.  But I am not going to get into why on Earth you want to do that.  ☺

## Further reading

- "[Filename Generation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation)".  Z shell manual.  sourceforge.

Comment: Note that `zsh -o extendedglob` is not the only shell where `^` needs to be quoted. Also in the Thompson shell, Bourne shell, rc, es, akanga, fish. In csh, tcsh, bash, it's only when at the start of the first word of a command line (usually not an issue as command names rarely start with `^`, but you could run into it in `echo \<newline>^` in `bash` for instance)